# How attach a weapon that simulates physics to a player's socket

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I want that when the weapon has no owner, it simulates physics. When it has an owner (player) it becomes static and lies in the socket on the arm. And when you throw it away, it simulates physics again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqZbo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U56Jd.png)

I want to do weapon picking like in Mount & Blade II: Bannerlord